# Make a javascript tag maker with limited options from txt file

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make a tagging tool to add skills as tags using JavaScript, something like LinkedIn or Upwork, where you enter all the skills that match your profile.
How to limit the options available to data in a txt file?

For example:
txt file:

Programming
Writing
Music
Teaching

Then the only available options to add are: "Programming", "Writing", "Music" and "Teaching" (user can't add extra tags).

Here is current code:

```
<div id ="app" class="tags-input" data-name="tags-input"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
  [].forEach.call(document.getElementsByClassName('tags-input'), function (el) {
    let hiddenInput = document.createElement('input'),
    mainInput = document.createElement('input'),
    tags = [];

    hiddenInput.setAttribute('type', 'hidden');
    hiddenInput.setAttribute('name', el.getAttribute('data-name'));

    mainInput.setAttribute('type', 'text');
    mainInput.classList.add('main-input');
    mainInput.addEventListener('input', function () {
      let enteredTags = mainInput.value.split(',');
      if (enteredTags.length > 1) {
        enteredTags.forEach(function (t) {
          let filteredTag = filterTag(t);
          if (filteredTag.length > 0)
            addTag(filteredTag);
        });
        mainInput.value = '';
      }
    });

    mainInput.addEventListener('keydown', function (e) {
      let keyCode = e.which || e.keyCode;
      if (keyCode === 8 && mainInput.value.length === 0 && tags.length > 0) {
        removeTag(tags.length - 1);
      }
    });

    el.appendChild(mainInput);
    el.appendChild(hiddenInput);

    function addTag (text) {
      let tag = {
        text: text,
        element: document.createElement('span'),
      };

      tag.element.classList.add('tag');
      tag.element.textContent = tag.text;

      let closeBtn = document.createElement('span');
      closeBtn.classList.add('close');
      closeBtn.addEventListener('click', function () {
        removeTag(tags.indexOf(tag));
      });
      tag.element.appendChild(closeBtn);

      tags.push(tag);

      el.insertBefore(tag.element, mainInput);

      refreshTags();
    }

    function removeTag (index) {
      let tag = tags[index];
      tags.splice(index, 1);
      el.removeChild(tag.element);
      refreshTags();
    }

    function refreshTags () {
      let tagsList = [];
      tags.forEach(function (t) {
        tagsList.push(t.text);
      });
      hiddenInput.value = tagsList.join(',');
    }

    function filterTag (tag) {
      return tag.replace(/[^\w -]/g, '').trim().replace(/\W+/g, '-');
    }
  });
</script>
```

Comment: So it basically comes down to that you need either a database, a json file, or some other method to store all the tags you want users to be able to select. That way, repetition is easily avoided and users can't add new tags themselves.

Comment: @Shilly I have a json file but I can't link the file to the javascript code any suggestions on how this is done or what part of the code I need to edit?

Comment: Hi Youhanna, I've tidied up your post a little.  P.s You're asking quite a few questions here. StackOverflow is best utilised when you focus on the one main problem.

Comment: If you host the json file in the same place as you host the website, you can get the file with a simple ajax call. Or just use a variable in your code if the tags can be hardcoded.

Comment: Hi @AlexanderWigmore I noticed, thanks a lot. I am sorry i am new here :D, the thing is that the problems are kind of related or can be solved together that's why I figured asking them together will help show what I am looking for.

Comment: @YouhannaSabry I don't have the time to give a proper answer currently, I mainly came here to just tidy up your question. Might be worth checking out these examples I just found though:

https://codepen.io/gyomb/pen/ZoONgZ

https://codepen.io/robalb/pen/JKpdjV

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I kind of found a workaround to do it.
It's not very efficient or the perfect solution but it does what I need.
Here is the code if anyone need it.
Hope it helps.

```
<div id ="app" class="tags-input" data-name="tags-input"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
let lines;
$.get('skills.txt',{},function(content){
    lines=content.split('\n');

    console.log(`"file.txt" contains ${lines.length} lines`)
    console.log(`First line : ${lines[0]}`)
});

[].forEach.call(document.getElementsByClassName('tags-input'), function (el) {
    let hiddenInput = document.createElement('input'),
    mainInput = document.createElement('input'),
    tags = [];

    hiddenInput.setAttribute('type', 'hidden');
    hiddenInput.setAttribute('name', el.getAttribute('data-name'));

    mainInput.setAttribute('type', 'text');
    mainInput.classList.add('main-input');
    mainInput.addEventListener('input', function () {
        let enteredTags = mainInput.value.split(' ');
        if (enteredTags.length > 1) {
            enteredTags.forEach(function (t) {
                let filteredTag = filterTag(t);
                if (filteredTag.length > 0)
                    addTag(filteredTag);
            });
            mainInput.value = '';
        }
    });

    mainInput.addEventListener('keydown', function (e) {
        let keyCode = e.which || e.keyCode;
        if (keyCode === 8 && mainInput.value.length === 0 && tags.length > 0) 
{
            removeTag(tags.length - 1);
        }
    });

    el.appendChild(mainInput);
    el.appendChild(hiddenInput);

    function addTag (text) {
        let tag = {
            text: text,
            element: document.createElement('span'),
        };

        tag.element.classList.add('tag');
        tag.element.textContent = tag.text;

        let closeBtn = document.createElement('span');
        closeBtn.classList.add('close');
        closeBtn.addEventListener('click', function () {
            removeTag(tags.indexOf(tag));
        });
        tag.element.appendChild(closeBtn);
        var available = 0;
        for (var i = lines.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            if(lines[i]==tag.text){
                available = 1;
            }
        }
        var exists = 0;
        for (var i = tags.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {

            if (tags[i].text==tag.text) {
                exists = 1;
            }
        }
        if (exists == 0 && available == 1) {
            tags.push(tag);

            el.insertBefore(tag.element, mainInput);

            refreshTags();
        }
    }

    function removeTag (index) {
        let tag = tags[index];
        tags.splice(index, 1);
        el.removeChild(tag.element);
        refreshTags();
    }

    function refreshTags () {
        let tagsList = [];
        tags.forEach(function (t) {
            tagsList.push(t.text);
        });
        hiddenInput.value = tagsList.join(',');
    }

    function filterTag (tag) {
        return tag.replace(/[^\w -]/g, '').trim().replace(/\W+/g, '-');
    }
});

</script>
```

Don't forget to include jQuery in the head

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
```